# c# пропал событие

Tags: c#

Здравствуете! Программа работал отлично. Я копировал все компоненты в panel и все обработчики не работает.
Когда нажимаю два раз на button он создается новый обработчик с приставки (button_1). Вопрос как я могу вернет все обработчики на месте?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, вы разрабатываете форму в дизайнере форм. В нем можно также назначать обработчики. Выбираете в дизайнере формы ваш button. В свойствах (панель Properties) переходите в закладку "События" (Events). Ниже из списка событий выбираете нужное событие, например, Click. И правее, из выпадающего списка выбираете нужный обработчик.
И так для каждого элемента управления, для каждого обрабатываемого события.

Comment: До копирование уже был событие! почему они не обрабатывается

Comment: Мне надо что все обработчики вернет на место

Comment: После копирования у копии кнопки не обрабатывается ни одно событие. Если хотите использовать старый обработчик (метод уже есть в коде) — его нужно назначить. Как это сделать — написано в ответе выше.

Comment: Там может 100 компонент, для каждое компонент так делать очень долго